# File transfer from server to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, fileserver

I want to use two servers in my Rails app (with nginx server) - first for web app, second for images. User can upload image in the first server. After upload, image transferred to second server at once. After transfer, user can view image in site. How to organize file transfer from server-to-server?

Comment: This isn't a question for SO. Go look up a few things on google and come back when you've tried a few things. You need to let us know what you've tried.

Comment: I do not know how best to do - post request, sockets, to make a general raid. Why not offer choices, I hope that is the most simple solution.

Comment: Have you read @melvyn's suggestion to enter ['scp', 'nfs', 'rsync'] into Google, read about it, try it, see what breaks? Then come back and ask again. That's your best place to start. S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thee are multiple ways to do this. I suggest you start by entering the following words into a search engine and come back with specific questions: nfs, scp, rsync, unison.

Comment: Thank you. But it is better to use when loading the user file? Immediately send or do the task in the background?

Comment: This depend on your requirements. Nfs is instantaneous, but requires that only one of the servers writes to the shared directory. Scp is event driven and requires solid error handling. Rsync and unison are periodic, Cron driven, but can handle two way replication, to some extent.